# Check if a slug is existing, else create a new product in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have here a code below that will insert products into the database in woocommerce :

```
$post = array(
  'post_author' => $user_id,
  'post_content' => '',
  'post_status' => "publish",
  'post_title' => $product->part_num,
  'post_parent' => '',
  'post_type' => "product",
); 
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
```

But, before inserting a new product, I want to check if a slug is existing in the database, else, I want to add a new one and append a number on the slug.

example input:

```
$new_url = sanitize_title('This Long Title is what My Post or Page might be');
```

output :

this-long-title-is-what-my-post-or-page-might-be

Now, I want to check if this slug is already existing in the database. If it is existing, I will append a number on the slug(just like what wordpress permalink is doing). If it is already existing, i want to output this as:

this-long-title-is-what-my-post-or-page-might-be-1

**I want to add new product into the database together with this new slug.**

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but just written that code. Try this and let me know

```
function slug_exists($slug){
   if(get_page_by_path( $slug, OBJECT, 'product' )){
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

$slug = 'your_slug';
$new_slug = $slug;
$c=1;
while(slug_exists($new_slug)){
  $new_slug = $slug.'-'.$c;
  $c++;
}
```

// $new_slug containes your desired slug

Comment: what is the use of  the parameter inside : function slug_exists($slug){